# CakePhp HtmlHelper link method

Tags: cakephp

If I write

```
debug($this->Html->link('pippo',array('controller'=>'customers','action'=>'index')));
```

the link is good

```
'<a href="<<document_root>/index">pippo</a>'
```

But If I write

```
   debug($this->Html->link('pippo','customers/index'));
```

it prints :

```
'<a href="/www/customers/customers/index">pippo</a>'
```

contrary to what the manual says.
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book does not say `customers/index` but `/customers/index`. Notice the / in front.

Also never use string notation for links that point to your application but the array notation. Routing doesn't work if you use strings plus the router has to decompile the string to array which can be a little overhead if you have plenty of links on a page.

So stick the array instead of the string.